# pandas dataframe fillna() not working?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have a data set in which I am performing a principal components analysis (PCA). I get a `ValueError` message when I try to transform the data. Below is some of the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA as sklearnPCA

data = pd.read_csv('test.csv',header=0)
X = data.ix[:,0:1000].values   # values of 1000 predictor variables
Y = data.ix[:,1000].values     # values of binary outcome variable
sklearn_pca = sklearnPCA(n_components=2)
X_std = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
```

It is here that I get the following error message:

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

So I then checked whether the original data set had any NaN values:

```
print(data.isnull().values.any())   # prints True
data.fillna(0)                      # replace NaN values with 0
print(data.isnull().values.any())   # prints True
```

I don't understand why `data.isnull().values.any()` is still printing `True` even after I replaced the NaN values with 0.

Answer (score 8):

There are two way to achieve, try replace in place:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(data=[0,float('nan'),2,3])   
print('BEFORE:', data.isnull().values.any())   # prints True

# fillna function
data.fillna(0, inplace=True)

print('AFTER:',data.isnull().values.any())   # prints False now :)
```

Or, use returned object:

```
data = data.fillna(0)
```

Both case have same result as following:

```
BEFORE: True
AFTER: False
```

Comment: Second one worked for me but not the first one. I am using it for float values. Any idea why is it so?

Comment: I have update my sample code as @Jean-Francois Fabre does, you can see they get same result.

Answer (score 3):

You have to replace data by the returned object from `fillna`

Small reproducer:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(data=[0,float('nan'),2,3])

print(data.isnull().values.any())   # prints True
data = data.fillna(0)                      # replace NaN values with 0
print(data.isnull().values.any())   # prints False now :)
```